# display, show and to_html doesn't work in iPython notebook

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython, show

I am trying to display or show()/to_html my dataframes inside an ipython notebook but it is throwing error "AttributeError". Only display(df1) is printing df schema as below:

```
DataFrame[name: string, age: bigint]
```

Here is my code:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

data = [('Alice',1),('Bob',2)]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, ['name','age'])
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df1, "df1_table")
df2 = sqlContext.sql("Select * from df1_table")

#display(df1)
HTML(df1.to_html)
df1.to_html()
```

any ideas?

Comment: the complete error was:  'AttributeError: DataFrame object has no attribute to_html'

Comment: Pardon my little knowledge, I ask this question to understand why it doesn't?

Comment: Well, i found this to_html() as an answer in another thread on stackoverflow, thats why.

Comment: Because it simply never had. Given what exactly is Spark DataFrame this arguably would be useless anyway. It looks like you've mistaken Spark DataFrame with Pandas DataFrame which are two completely different things.

Comment: @zero323, Thanks. Then my question is how can i view the contents of spark dataframe in this notebook?

Comment: If data is small enough to be converted to local data structure you can collect it an convert to pandas DF (`toPandas`)

Comment: ok, so it means that ipython has limited ability to do everything that we need to do. Again, sorry for my initial knowledge, what if I brought my code to independent of any such environment and start coding in eclipse (no boundaries), will that work for everything supplied by pyspark? I don't wana limit myself.